# Proxy pattern in Javascript without inbuilt Proxy class

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, es6-proxy, proxy-pattern

I want to intercept requests to `Object A` and log some message and forward the request back to Object A

Es6 proxies and reflect would be a good use case for this, but I’ll be taking a huge performance hit.
I want to implement a proxy on my own, what are the edge cases I’ll need to handle. I’m asking this because JS behaves pretty weird in different scopes

Comment: What do you mean by `...ill be taking a huge performance hit.`

Comment: What kind of "requests" are you talking about?

Comment: "*JS behaves pretty weird in different scopes*" - not sure what you mean. Can you please show the code of your attempt?

Comment: @bill.gates Reflection in proxy is a costly operation.